# Query number of rooted android devices using the app

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, crashlytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've noticed Firebase Crashlytics has knowledge whether device is rooted or no:

[image]

Is it possible to get this data via query - minimum for devices that crashed, maximum for any device using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the Crashlytics data into [BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export). However, as this information is only collected by Crashlytics, you will be able to obtain the number of rooted devices that have reported a crash but this won't tell you the percentage of rooted devices out of all the devices using the app as there could be rooted devices that haven't reported crashes.

This is an example on how to query this information from the Crashlytics dataset:

```
SELECT COUNT(installation_uuid) as rooted_crashed_devices from (
  SELECT installation_uuid FROM `<Crashlytics table>` 
  WHERE operating_system.modification_state = 'MODIFIED'
  GROUP BY installation_uuid
);
```

This is the result from the query:

| rooted_crashed_devices |
| --- |
| 500 |

A possible workaround could be sending this information as an [Analytics event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#log_events_3), and then use BigQuery to get this information.

Comment: Thank you, certainly works! Do you happen to know if same thing is available under analytical events somewhere? (to pull data not just for audience who crashed, but for everyone).

Comment: I mean without actually sending it to GA manually - if it's being present with every GA event somehow, by default - just like with crashes info.

Comment: Looking into the BigQuery schema for Analytics, there is some information related to the device, but nothing that tells you if the device is rooted. See this link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en